# WIN 10 Home 32-Bit apps (microsoft Office, Teamviewer)

Tags: windows-10

As a Mac Catalina Admin (here only 64 Bit apps working) i have a question about 32-Bit apps:
in taskmgr i see on my WIN 10 system (about 2 years old) - MS Office 365 in 32-bit mode.
is this normal or can i set a default, that only 64 bit version apps are installed?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to chose if you want to have 32 or 64 bit on installation. If you find 32 bit on your system, you might have (accidentially) downloaded or chosen the 32 bit version. This is normally no problem, though. If you need the 64bit version, just download the installer and install the 64 bit. Make sure to remove the 32 bit version beforehand!

Comment: No, @music2myear is correct; you may install only one version, 64 or 32-bit, not both. Note also that while you can install either version on 64-bit Windows, you can only install the 32-bit version on 32-bit Windows.

Comment: That's what I said?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select the bitness of an application to run. Bitness is defined by the development of an application.

If you wish to run a 64bit program then you need to install the 64bit version of that program.

For some programs that offer both variants you could install both and then run the version you need, but I don't believe you can install both variations of Office on a single computer at the same time due to how Office integrates with the OS.

So, your only solution is to install the version you require to begin with.